# Excel 2016: explore columns on Sheet 1, if part of content matches with cell on Sheet 2, then copy content from Sheet 2

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison

I have 2 Sheets in one file

Sheet 1 has a column "Article" with old article descriptions like "PO11AD00 facing tiles Island"

Sheet 2 has two columns: 
"Old Article" with PO11AD00
and 
"New Article" with PWU09RLX1

I need either to replace old article in Sheet 1 name with New Article from Sheet 2, or add new column to Sheet 1 with New Article next to Old Article

Is it possible to explore array on Sheet 1 for a content from Sheet 2 and if matches, copy content from another cell on a Sheet 2?

Thank You in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You CAN do that with VLOOKUP().  For more details see [this help page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).

But if you try to replace the Article that you look up, you'll get a circular reference error.

Suggest you create a new column on Sheet 1 - maybe "New Article".  Then enter this formula in the first row of that column:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A2:B50,2,FALSE),"")
```

and fill down.  This assumes the first article on Sheet 1 is in A2, and the old and new articles on Sheet 2 are in Columns A and B, starting in A2 and extending down to B50.  You should change those parameters as necessary.

This formula will list any new articles in the new column if it finds them, and list a blank if there isn't a new article to find.

Then you can copy any new article and paste it over the old article in column A (be sure to use Paste Special > Values to do this.)

Comment: Thanks. I went a bit a long way.  
I have Divided "PO11AD00 facing tiles Island" into 2 columns with Data -> Text to Columns  
So I got 2 separate Columns with Old Article Number and Article Description  
Then on a Sheet 1 I have added new Column with a formula:
`=VLOOKUP(C5,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)`
which compares Old Article on Sheet 1 with Article on Sheet 2, and copy New Article to New column on a Sheet 1  
Thanks once again!

Comment: You're welcome.  If you found this helpful, you can [accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)